# Work done propelling objects into orbit.

Tags: calculus, physics

I am currently working on a few problems but as of now I am stuck and unsure what to do. My confusion isn't in the mathematical computations but in the question itself. My question that I am working on is comparing the work done by propelling a single object into orbit of all 8 planets. Obviously I can look up the orbiting altitude for earth but other planets start to confuse me. I decided to use Newton's law of Universal Gravitation to find the variable d (distance between the planet and the object) but I always get a huge unreasonable number. Is there another way I can estimate the work done by launching one object into orbit around the planets? As of now I would find a function for the change in work and integrate from the planets radius to the distance I got from Newton's law of Universal Gravitation. Please help me someone.

Okay so for clarification here is one of my answers that I arrived to. This is for Venus. 
$$F(x)=\frac C {x^2}$$  where C is the Constant of proportionality.
then when using the weight of the module being launched 380552.711 and the radius of Venus 6,051,000 m I get 
$$380552.711=\frac C {6051000^2}$$
and $$C= 13,933,785,672,733,311,000$$
now we have the 
$$\Delta W= \frac{13,933,785,672,733,311,000}{x^2}\Delta x$$

Now is the time that I would solve for the distance between the satellite and the planet. I solve for d from Newton's law of Universal Gravitation (which I suspect is the wrong thing to do and I get the distance to be $1.89218 \times 10^7$.
I use the radius of Venus as the lower bound of integration and the distance I just solved for plus the radius of venus for my upper bound. Once I solve for work by integrating the change in work function I got I get the work done to be $1.711\times 10^{13}$ joules.

Comment: Would conservation of energy not apply?

Comment: "Into orbit" is what you need to think about. What does an orbit mean? What determines how far an object orbits? First clarify how you understand these things and we can help you further.

Comment: Launching from where? @copper.hat's approach is almost certainly the one you want to use. Note however that rocket propulsion is quite inefficient.

Comment: @dfeuer launching from the planets surface. And sorry for the ambiguous language. I don't have much of an understanding of satellite orbits other than the orbiting altitudes of satellites on earth.

Comment: For example, Mercury doesn't have any satellites orbiting it so how can I know where to say the distance is? I got about 241 km and for Venus I got about 18,000 km. Obviously these numbers don't make sense

Comment: @dfeuer circular would be fine. elliptica might be too much for this particular problem

Comment: I would disregard the plane I would orbit in.

Comment: Let's start with "how far above the planet is the satellite orbiting?". This will tell us how much energy it has, since we can find the potential energy (Newton's Universal law) and kinetic energy (uniform circular motion).

Comment: Caution: the relationship between orbital speed and orbital energy does not match most people's intuition.

Comment: Sorry for the math not showing up correctly... and I don't know how far above the planet to say that the satellite is orbiting. That is what I am trying to find out @levitopher

Comment: @user100710, you probably don't want the orbit to intersect the surface, or go too far into the atmosphere of any planet that has one.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't. I would like to assume that once it's in orbit it can sustain the orbit but the only thing that i am considering when calculating the work is the action of propelling the satellite up into a altitude high enough for orbit.

Comment: In the absence of an atmosphere, the orbit can be as close to the surface as you like.  If there is an atmosphere, drag will cause the orbit to eventually decay, anywhere below a synchronous orbit (presuming the atmosphere is rotating in synch with the planet).
The rate of decay will depend on the cross-sectional area to mass ratio of the satellite.

Comment: @RobertIsrael So you say that the rate of decay will depend on the cross-sectional area to mass ration of the satellite. How does that apply itself to this problem. Is there a formula of some kind I can apply to this or no? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @user100710, Robert Israel refers to an approximation for drag through the atmosphere that works pretty well at the low atmospheric densities involved.

Comment: The point is that there is no particular height that you can say is "enough".  A Google search turns up http://www.ips.gov.au/Category/Educational/Space%20Weather/Space%20Weather%20Effects/SatelliteOrbitalDecayCalculations.pdf which gives you an idea of some of the calculations involved.

Answer (score 2):

There are some apparently open questions in regard to this problem, and I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are doing above. So I will make a suggestion for a way to approach it. Fair warning - I am going to put my satellites into orbit with zero kinetic energy - in other words, I'm only going to oppose gravity and not set them orbiting around the planets. I choose to do this because your original answer suggested you are mostly interested in that part of the problem. Using the work-energy theorem and uniform circular motion, you could add the circular motion of the satellite.

Since we can create stable orbits "anywhere" above a planet, let's assume  a constant orbital distance relative to the radius of the body. If the body has a radius of $R$, let's assume each satellite orbits at a radius of $r_s=\gamma R$, where $\gamma$ is some constant. The ISS orbits at like 300 km, so $\gamma \sim (6300+300)/6300 \sim 1.05$ in that case.

Now the work required to launch a satellite into that orbit comes from the force of thrust, which is needed to oppose the force of gravity:
$$F_t(p_i)=\frac{GM(p_i)m}{r^2}$$
Here I am writing "$p_i$" as "planet $i$", so $M(p_i)$ is the mass of planet $i$, I hope that is not too confusing. $m$ is the mass of our satellite and $G$ is the gravitational constant. The work required is the integral of the force from the radius of the planet to the radius of the orbit:
$$W(p_i)=\int_{R(p_i)}^{r_s(p_i)} F_t(p_i) dr=GM(p_i)m\int_{R(p_i)}^{\gamma R(p_i)}\frac{dr}{r^2}$$
Notice that this illustrates one of the problems with your solution - since the force depends on the radius, you cannot simply write $\Delta W=F\Delta x$, you have to take the integral to get the right answer.

I hope this gives you enough to get started - if you still have problems I will add more details. The answer will depend on the value of $\gamma$ that you choose. This was not the only possible way to parametrize the problem. I think another reasonable way would have been to shoot for a constant orbital velocity - but you might run into some problems with flying inside a planet if you choose poorly!

Additionally, don't be worried about large numbers - the energy of a baseball being thrown by a professional pitcher is like 100 J, so launching a spaceship should easily be more than a million times that, right? Putting a baseball ($m$=150 g) into orbit (as above) takes around $10^8$ J. Expect big numbers!

Comment: Thank you, the scope of my question was pretty unclear but you cleared up some of the most confusing aspects of this question for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At the burnout $(t=0)$, the free flight is decided by the initial conditions $\mathbf r_0=\mathbf r (0)$ and $\mathbf v_0=\mathbf v (0)$.

The point is that the orbit is elliptic (right-hand inequality) and the satellite does not hit the surface of the planet (left-hand inequality) if $$\sqrt {\frac {GM}{r_0}} \le
 v_0 < \sqrt {\frac {2GM}{r_0}} \quad \quad (r_0>R)$$ A special *altitude* does not exist because the condition contains both $r_0$ and $v_0 \,$.

Moreover note that the condition contains only the initial speed (not the initial velocity).